# How to use api.dpd.co.uk api integration with php

Tags: php, api

Hi I'm working as web developer from several years and did not use any api before today. Now I have to integrate a shipping company's api with clients website and I'm trying to understand its api documentation but did not have any useful result. client provided me a [pdf](https://www.dropbox.com/s/f4ntui9izc0a7nj/Shipping_API_1_0_1.pdf) file that's difficult to understand for me. can anybody help me as soon as possible. I should be very grateful I any one can help me

last code that i try:

```
$url="api.dpd.co.uk/user/?action=login HTTP/1.1";

$options = array(
    'http' => array(
        'method'  => 'POST',
        'Host'  => 'api.dpd.co.uk',
        'method'  => 'POST',
        'header'=>  "Content-Type: application/json\r\n" .
                    "Accept: application/json\r\n".
                    "Authorization: Basic RFNNSVRIOk1ZUEFTU1dE".
                    "GEOClient:".base64_encode("account/123456").
                    "Content-Length: 0"
      )
);


$context     = stream_context_create($options);
$result      = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
$response    = json_decode($result);
echo var_dump($response);
```

assistance to solve this issue would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Please help me soon if anyone can

Comment: [OOT] Why need `echo` when you `var_dump()`?

Answer (score 8):

Though someone might find this useful - this a a load of different methods working for the api.dpd.co.uk - couple of notes - you need to put your account number in - and your username and password - also for creating shipments make sure collectionDate is in the future or it just throws a General Application Error..

```
<?php
$BASE="https://api.dpd.co.uk";

$method = '/user/?action=login';

$url = $BASE.$method;

$options = array(
    'http' => array(
        'method'  => 'POST',
        'Host'  => 'api.dpd.co.uk',
        'header'=>  "Content-Type: application/json\r\n" .
                    "Accept: application/json\r\n".
                    "Authorization: Basic ". base64_encode("user:pass") ."\r\n".
                    "GEOClient: account/123456\r\n".
                    "Content-Length: 0"
      )
);


$context     = stream_context_create($options);

$result      = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
$response    = json_decode($result);
//echo var_dump($response);

$data=(json_decode($result,true));
$session=$data['data']['geoSession'];
echo $session;

//$session="MTAuMjYuMy4yMDd8LTczODMzNzE4MA==";


// get some services...
/*
/shipping/network/?collectionDetails.address.locality=Birmingham&collectionDetails.
address.county=West%20Midlands&collectionDetails.address.postcode=B661BY&collection
Details.address.countyCode=GB&deliveryDetails.address.locality=Birmingham&deliveryD
etails.address.county=West%20Midlands&deliveryDetails.address.postcode=B11AA&delive
ryDetails.address.countyCode=GB&deliveryDirection=1&numberOfParcels=1&totalWeight=5
&shipmentType=0 HTTP/1.1
Host: api.dpd.co.uk
Accept: application/json
GEOClient: account/123456
GEOSession: 1234567890ABCDEFGHIJK

*/

$method = '/shipping/network/?collectionDetails.address.locality=Birmingham&collectionDetails.address.county=West%20Midlands&collectionDetails.address.postcode=B661BY&collectionDetails.address.countyCode=GB&deliveryDetails.address.locality=Birmingham&deliveryDetails.address.county=West%20Midlands&deliveryDetails.address.postcode=B11AA&deliveryDetails.address.countyCode=GB&deliveryDirection=1&numberOfParcels=1&totalWeight=5&shipmentType=0&collectionDetails.address.countryCode=GB&deliveryDetails.address.countryCode=GB';

$url = $BASE.$method;

$options = array(
    'http' => array(
        'method'  => 'GET',
        'Host'  => 'api.dpd.co.uk',
        'header'=>  "Content-Type: application/json\r\n" .
                    "Accept: application/json\r\n".
                    "GEOClient: account/123456\r\n".
                    "GEOSession: ".$session."\r\n".
                    "Content-Length: 0"
      )
);

$context     = stream_context_create($options);

$result      = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
$response    = json_decode($result);
//echo var_dump($response);

$data=(json_decode($result,true));
var_dump($data);

//

$method = '/shipping/country/GB';

$url = $BASE.$method;

$options = array(
    'http' => array(
        'method'  => 'GET',
        'Host'  => 'api.dpd.co.uk',
        'header'=>  "Content-Type: application/json\r\n" .
                    "Accept: application/json\r\n".
                    "GEOClient: account/123456\r\n".
                    "GEOSession: ".$session."\r\n".
                    "Content-Length: 0"
      )
);

$context     = stream_context_create($options);

$result      = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
$response    = json_decode($result);
//echo var_dump($response);

$data=(json_decode($result,true));
var_dump($data);

$method = '/shipping/country/GB';

$url = $BASE.$method;

$options = array(
    'http' => array(
        'method'  => 'GET',
        'Host'  => 'api.dpd.co.uk',
        'header'=>  "Content-Type: application/json\r\n" .
                    "Accept: application/json\r\n".
                    "GEOClient: account/123456\r\n".
                    "GEOSession: ".$session."\r\n".
                    "Content-Length: 0"
      )
);

$context     = stream_context_create($options);

$result      = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
$response    = json_decode($result);
//echo var_dump($response);

$data=(json_decode($result,true));
var_dump($data);

$method = '/shipping/country';

$url = $BASE.$method;

$options = array(
    'http' => array(
        'method'  => 'GET',
        'Host'  => 'api.dpd.co.uk',
        'header'=>  "Content-Type: application/json\r\n" .
                    "Accept: application/json\r\n".
                    "GEOClient: account/123456\r\n".
                    "GEOSession: ".$session."\r\n".
                    "Content-Length: 0"
      )
);

$context     = stream_context_create($options);

$result      = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
$response    = json_decode($result);
//echo var_dump($response);

$data=(json_decode($result,true));
var_dump($data);

// /shipping/network/812/

$method = '/shipping/network/812/';

$url = $BASE.$method;

$options = array(
    'http' => array(
        'method'  => 'GET',
        'Host'  => 'api.dpd.co.uk',
        'header'=>  "Content-Type: application/json\r\n" .
                    "Accept: application/json\r\n".
                    "GEOClient: account/123456\r\n".
                    "GEOSession: ".$session."\r\n".
                    "Content-Length: 0"
      )
);

$context     = stream_context_create($options);

$result      = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
$response    = json_decode($result);
//echo var_dump($response);

$data=(json_decode($result,true));
var_dump($data);


// /shipping/shipment

$method = '/shipping/shipment';

$url = $BASE.$method;
$json='{
                        "job_id": null,
                        "collectionOnDelivery": false,
                        "invoice": null,
                        "collectionDate": "2014-11-13T016:00:00",
                        "consolidate": false,
                        "consignment": [{
                            "consignmentNumber": null,
                            "consignmentRef": null,
                            "parcels": [],
                            "collectionDetails": {
                            "contactDetails": {
                            "contactName": "My Contact",
                            "telephone": "0121 500 2500"
                            },
                            "address": {
                            "organisation": "GeoPostUK Ltd",
                            "countryCode": "GB",
                            "postcode": "B66 1BY",
                            "street": "Roebuck Lane",
                            "locality": "Smethwick",
                            "town": "Birmingham",
                            "county": "West Midlands"
                            }
                            },
                            "deliveryDetails": {"contactDetails": {
                            "contactName": "My Contact",
                            "telephone": "0121 500 2500"
                            },
                            "address": {
                            "organisation": "GeoPostUK Ltd",
                            "countryCode": "GB",
                            "postcode": "B66 1BY",
                            "street": "Roebuck Lane",
                            "locality": "Smethwick",
                            "town": "Birmingham",
                            "county": "West Midlands"
                            },
                            "notificationDetails": {
                            "email": "my.email@geopostuk.com",
                            "mobile": "07921000001"
                            }
                            },
                            "networkCode": "1^01",
                            "numberOfParcels": 1,
                            "totalWeight": 5,
                            "shippingRef1": "My Ref 1",
                            "shippingRef2": "My Ref 2",
                            "shippingRef3": "My Ref 3",
                            "customsValue": null,
                            "deliveryInstructions": "Please deliver with neighbour",
                            "parcelDescription": "",
                            "liabilityValue": null,
                            "liability": false
                            }]
                        }';
$json=(str_replace(" ", "", $json));
$json=(str_replace("\n", "", $json));
$json=(str_replace("    ", "", $json));
//exit();
$length=strlen($json);
echo $length;
$options = array(
    'http' => array(
        'method'  => 'POST',
        'Host'  => 'api.dpd.co.uk',
        'header'=>  "Content-Type: application/json\r\n" .
                    "Accept: application/json\r\n".
                    "GEOClient: account/123456\r\n".
                    "GEOSession: ".$session."\r\n".
                    "Content-Length: ".$length."\r\n",
        'content'=> $json
      )
);
var_dump($options);
$context     = stream_context_create($options);
echo var_dump($context);
$result      = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);


$response    = json_decode($result);

$data=(json_decode($result,true));
var_dump($data);

$shipmentId=$data['data']['shipmentId'];
///shipping/shipment/[shipmentId]/label/
echo $shipmentId;

$method = '/shipping/shipment/'.$shipmentId.'/label/';

$url = $BASE.$method;

$options = array(
    'http' => array(
        'method'  => 'GET',
        'Host'  => 'api.dpd.co.uk',
        'header'=>  "Accept: text/html\r\n".
                    "GEOClient: account/123456\r\n".
                    "GEOSession: ".$session."\r\n"
                    )
);

$context     = stream_context_create($options);

$result      = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
$response    = json_decode($result);
echo $result;


?>
```

Answer (score 2):

wrote an authentication class if anyone's interested?

```php
class Authentication {
    private $url;
    private $timeout;
    private $ch;
    private $headers;
    private $username;
    private $password;
    private $accountNo;
    public function __construct($url, $username, $password, $accountNo, $timeout='5', $headers=array()) {
        $this->headers = array( 'Content-Type: application/json',
            'Accept: application/json',
            'Authorization: Basic ' . base64_encode($username . ':' . $password),
            'GEOClient: ' . $username . '/' . $accountNo,
            'Content-Length: 0'
        );
        $this->url = $url . '/user/?action=login';
        $this->timeout = $timeout;
        $this->headers = array_merge($this->headers, $headers);
        $this->ch = curl_init();
    }
    public function __destruct() {
        curl_close($this->ch);
    }
    public function doAuthentication() {
        curl_setopt_array($this->ch, array(
            CURLOPT_URL => $this->url,
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
            CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => $this->timeout,
            CURLOPT_USERAGENT => 'Spry Web Design dev',
            CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $this->headers,
            CURLOPT_POST => true
        ));
        $authPost = curl_exec($this->ch);
        $data = json_decode($authPost, true);
        return $data['data']['geoSession'];
    }
};

// example usage below
$client = new Authentication("URL", 'USERNAME', 'PASSWORD', 'ACCOUNT_NO');
echo $result = $client->doAuthentication();
```

Comment: Thanks for this dude

Answer (score 1):

Recently I have connected DPD API on my site. for testing, I created the repo if want, please check out. because I have implemented all API enpoint on this repository.

LINK: https://github.com/najathi/dpd-api-shipping-uk

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this hope this will help. you must have username, password and account number of account of (dpd.co.uk).

```
$BASE="https://api.dpd.co.uk";
$method = '/user/?action=login';

$url = $BASE.$method;

$options = array(
    'http' => array(
        'method'  => 'POST',
        'Host'  => 'api.dpd.co.uk',
        'header'=>  "Content-Type: application/json\r\n" .
                    "Accept: application/json\r\n".
                    "Authorization: Basic ". base64_encode("username:password") ."\r\n".
                    "GEOClient: account/your account number\r\n".
                    "Content-Length: 0"
      )
);


$context     = stream_context_create($options);

$result      = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
$response    = json_decode($result);
echo var_dump($response);
```

Comment: now its with error Warning: file_get_contents(https://api.dpd.co.uk/user/?action=login) [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: No error in D:\wamp\www\recent\pharma\dpd.php on line 35
NULL

Answer (score 0):

You must have account on dpd.co.uk. dummy values will not work like (account/123456) or dummy password like(DSMITH:MYPASSWD) you have to put you api account number and username and password there which http://dpd.co.uk will provide you for api than this will work. use below link for api account on http://www.dpd.co.uk/apps/api/

Answer (score 0):

This for me was the best way to authorize login using Zend library.

```
        $BASE="https://api.dpd.co.uk";
        $method = '/user/?action=login';
        $url = $BASE.$method;

        $client = new Zend_Http_Client($url);
        $client->setMethod(Zend_Http_Client::POST);
        $client->setHeaders('Host', 'api.dpd.co.uk');
        $client->setHeaders(Zend_Http_Client::CONTENT_TYPE, 'application/json');
        $client->setHeaders('Accept', 'application/json');
        $client->setHeaders('Authorization', 'Basic '. base64_encode('username:password'));
        $client->setHeaders('GEOClient', 'account name/account number');
        $client->setHeaders('Content-Length', '0');
        $response = $client->request();
        $body = Zend_Json::decode($response->getBody());
        $geoSession =   $body['data']['geoSession'];
```