# Whenever I clean adt project it creates a bundles of error of R.layout and some others

Tags: android, eclipse, adt

I hae recently started android app development and have to face a problem. I've developed a small app to increase or decrease a label's value by 1 each. It was successfully developed and was working but after I edit the app_name(sting) value from "strings.xml" but it generated the error than I select clean option from project menu but number of errors increase instead of decrease.

Please guide me about this issue guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: Post string resource of `string.xml`.

Comment: Did you build the project after cleaning it?

Comment: Restart the eclipse first and then if error persists give some clue to us.

Comment: Error coming due to your project R class not generated and R class is not generated due to your project resource problem try to solve your resource problem it's may be on String.xml or layout.xml etc.

Comment: the erors are in the lines where any code code with R i.e R.layout, R.Id. shows error message "layout cannot be resolved or is not a field", "id cannot be resolved or is not a field" and so on

Comment: builed automaticaly checked and "build" option is as disabled

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you R.java file will be automatically deleted on cleaning the project if any xml file in the project having error so first correct your errors in strings.xml file then clean the project . you must have changed.

```
<string name="app_name">your app name</string>
```

app_name here . if you have done so then again make it as it was or go in manifest file

```
<application>
...
android:label="@string/app_name"
</application>
```

also change here the name what you given in strings.xml file.
hope you understands ...

Comment: there's no error in string.xml the error icon is on R.Java

Comment: can u help me for my other question that is about php api I did not received any  answer or any comment on that question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23636793/how-to-use-api-dpd-co-uk-api-integration-with-php

Comment: sorry i am android developer i cant help you in that question. i did not commented there because to comment i need 50 reputation, sorry.

Comment: ok thanks. I'll contact you if I'll have any problem in android development.